# How to insert an entity in a specific layout in Autocad using .net?

Tags: c#, autocad

I am trying to insert a blockReference (in my case a legend) into a specific layout amongst other layouts.

Here it's the code that I used:

```
BlockTable blockTable = transaction.GetObject(database.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForWrite) as BlockTable;
BlockTableRecord blkTbRecPaper = transaction.GetObject(blockTable[BlockTableRecord.PaperSpace], OpenMode.ForWrite) as BlockTableRecord;
blkTbRecPaper.AppendEntity(blockReference);
```

My problem is that it only works when the last selected layout is the one that I am looking for. Is there a way to directly specify the wanted layout instead addin the blockReference into the blockTableREcord of the paper space ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open the layout dictionary in order to get all layouts on the drawing. Then you can open the respective BlockTableRecord and insert the new block reference.

```
using (Transaction tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
{
    DBDictionary layoutDic
        = tr.GetObject(
                        db.LayoutDictionaryId,
                        OpenMode.ForRead,
                        false
                      ) as DBDictionary;

    foreach (DBDictionaryEntry entry in layoutDic)
    {
        ObjectId layoutId = entry.Value;

        Layout layout
            = tr.GetObject(
                            layoutId,
                            OpenMode.ForRead
                          ) as Layout;

        ed.WriteMessage(
            String.Format(
                            "{0}--> {1}",
                            Environment.NewLine,
                            layout.LayoutName
                         )
                       );
    }
    tr.Commit();
}
```

See a better sample at http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/05/listing-the-layout-names.html

Comment: Thanks @Augusto. Here it's how I add my blockReference: 

`BlockTableRecord blkTabRec = transaction.GetObject(layout.BlockTableRecordId, OpenMode.ForWrite) as BlockTableRecord;'
            legendEntries[0].Load(transaction, blkTabRec);`

Comment: My load method makes the legend entry (entities) to be added in the blockTable Record of the layer and the transaction.